# Eclipse Not opening and shows error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just wanted to open my eclipse to begin an android project , but it gives me this error :

> An Error has occured. See the log file

In the log file I have:

> "!SESSION 2014-02-09 12:11:25.690
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685 java.version=1.7.0_17
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product Command-line arguments: 
>   -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2014-02-09 12:11:26.310 !MESSAGE
>   [SCR] Exception while activating instance
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager@5d1a4ce8
>   of component org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1810)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.getMethod(ServiceComponent.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:213)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    ... 15 more
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2014-02-09 12:11:26.312 !MESSAGE
>   [SCR] Exception while activating instance
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager@5d1a4ce8
>   of component org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1810)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.getMethod(ServiceComponent.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:213)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    ... 15 more
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-02-09 12:11:26.670 !MESSAGE An error
>   occurred while automatically activating bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.workbench (249). !STACK 0
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin for bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.workbench is invalid   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
>     ... 36 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWTError  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    ... 42 more
>   Root exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/eclipse/swt/SWTError  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError    at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    ... 42 more
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-02-09 12:11:26.950 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException:
>   Plug-in "org.eclipse.ui.ide.application" was unable to instantiate
>   class "org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication".   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
>     ... 15 more Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException:
>   An error occurred while automatically activating bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.workbench (249).   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    ... 21 more
>   Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin for bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.workbench is invalid   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
>     ... 30 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/eclipse/swt/SWTError  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
>     ... 36 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWTError  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    ... 42 more
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 4 0 2014-02-09 12:11:27.178
>   !MESSAGE [SCR] Error while attempting to deactivate instance of
>   component Component[  name = org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme  activate
>   = activate    deactivate = deactivate     modified =      configuration-policy = optional     factory = null  autoenable = true   immediate = true    implementation =
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager   state =
>   Disabled  properties =    serviceFactory = false  serviceInterface =
>   [org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme.IThemeManager]   references = null
>     located in bundle =
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.3.v20120806-170624 [101] ] !STACK
>   0 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1810)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.getMethod(ServiceComponent.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.deactivate(ServiceComponent.java:337)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.deactivate(ServiceComponentProp.java:161)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.dispose(ServiceComponentProp.java:389)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.dispose(ServiceComponentProp.java:102)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(InstanceProcess.java:366)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(InstanceProcess.java:306)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.disposeComponentConfigs(Resolver.java:717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.disableComponents(Resolver.java:693)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.stoppingBundle(SCRManager.java:554)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.bundleChanged(SCRManager.java:233)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEventPrivileged(Framework.java:1568)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1504)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1499)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:506)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:566)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1206)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:592)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:284)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:692)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:600)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:399)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:199)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    ... 38 more
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 4 0 2014-02-09 12:11:27.180
>   !MESSAGE [SCR] Error while attempting to deactivate instance of
>   component Component[  name = org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme  activate
>   = activate    deactivate = deactivate     modified =      configuration-policy = optional     factory = null  autoenable = true   immediate = true    implementation =
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager   state =
>   Disabled  properties =    serviceFactory = false  serviceInterface =
>   [org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme.IThemeManager]   references = null
>     located in bundle =
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.3.v20120806-170624 [101] ] !STACK
>   0 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1810)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.getMethod(ServiceComponent.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.deactivate(ServiceComponent.java:337)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.deactivate(ServiceComponentProp.java:161)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.dispose(ServiceComponentProp.java:389)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.dispose(ServiceComponentProp.java:102)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(InstanceProcess.java:366)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(InstanceProcess.java:306)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.disposeComponentConfigs(Resolver.java:717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.disableComponents(Resolver.java:693)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.stoppingBundle(SCRManager.java:554)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.bundleChanged(SCRManager.java:233)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEventPrivileged(Framework.java:1568)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1504)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1499)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:506)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:566)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1206)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:592)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:284)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:692)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:600)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:399)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:199)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    ... 38 more

I haven't seen such error and some of the suggestions on other topics didn't help and I don't know where to begin in this long log file. I'll appreciate if someone can help me with this .

Comment: Thanks , It's the log file , I just put it in quotes

Comment: try to re-open after restart your system.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display` There is no such class in Android. What API are you using?

Comment: try opening the eclipse with new work space, does it open? if opens then as a last resort (if you do not have much projects) try importing the android project again..

Comment: API 19 . and yes it did work before. I tried to open eclipse with -clean and also tried to remove the .resource folder of my work space but I still get the errors , I guess it's easier to reinstall .

Comment: I suggest you can download the SDK bundle from android website to install eclipse again.

Answer (score 0):

[www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/156204/](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/156204/)‎ 
please check on site or delete and get a new ecllipse version for your system compatible.